# pass sort operator

Tags: swift2

Is it possible to pass either `<,>` operators to a function to alter a `sortInPlace` call? As opposed to copying this function and changing the `>` or manually checking another argument and sorting with conditional logic.

```
mutating func sortTasksPriorityAscending() {
    self.tasks.sortInPlace {$0.priority > $1.priority}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the trouble ???

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr.sortInPlace(>)
print(arr) // [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

in your case, where tasks is an array of Task:Comparable, then just define the correct version of <
for example ...

```
struct S: Comparable {
    var i: Int
}
func <(lhs: S, rhs: S)->Bool {
    return lhs.i < rhs.i
}
func ==(lhs: S, rhs: S)->Bool {
    return lhs.i == rhs.i
}
var arr = [S(i: 2),S(i: 3),S(i: 1)]
arr.sortInPlace(<)
print(arr) // [S(i: 1), S(i: 2), S(i: 3)]
arr.sortInPlace(>)
print(arr) // [S(i: 3), S(i: 2), S(i: 1)]
```

UPDATE

probably i don't understand you question ??

```
func foo(arr:[S], sortop: (S,S)->Bool) {
    var arr = arr
    arr.sortInPlace(sortop)
    print(arr)
}

foo(arr, sortop: >)
foo(arr, sortop: <)
```

Comment: im sorting on a custom property and i wanted to pass the operator to the function if possible

Comment: that is in my answer, isn't it?